# Working with expandable tableview cells and dequeueReusableCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've set a up a simple project to test out various TableView functionalities in swift, in particular enabling expandable cells.

I've gotten the expandable cell to work, in this project the first cell contains a label which displays todays date. When clicked it expands the cell beneath which contains a DatePicker. However I've noticed some strange behaviour in how the animation takes effect:

1. When the cell first expands, from cell 11 onwards, it slides over the top of the following cells (12,13,14... etc). It then contracts in the same manner.
2. The second time the cell expands it works as expected, pushing all cells down, however when it contracts it behaves in the same manner as in the first instance, sliding from cell 11 over the top of the higher numbered cells.
3. If I double tap the first cell the datePicker vanishes almost instantly (leaving a blank cell to contract).

Any insights into the above would be greatly appreciated.

I've set the background of all the odd cells blue, and the animation speed to 2sec to help with viewing the issues.

Thanks in advance.

**TableViewController**

```
import UIKit

protocol DateLabelDelegate: AnyObject {
    func setDateLabel(_ text: String)
}

protocol DatePickerVisibilityDelegate: AnyObject {
    func showCell(cellExpanded: Bool)
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var dateCellExpanded: Bool = false
    var date: String = String()
    let todayDate = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    weak var dateLabelDelegate: DateLabelDelegate?
    weak var datePickerVisibilityDelegate: DatePickerVisibilityDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableViewSetup()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        let result = formatter.string(from: todayDate)
        date = "Date: \(result)"
    }

    func tableViewSetup() {
        // Format tableView
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero) // Removes Empty Cells
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none

        // Register Cells
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DatePickerCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DatePickerCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DateLabelCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DateLabelCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SampleTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SampleTableViewCell")
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in _: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateLabelCell", for: indexPath) as! DateLabelCell
            cell.setDateLabel(date)
            return cell

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DatePickerCell", for: indexPath) as! DatePickerCell
            cell.dateDelegate = self
            cell.showCell(cellExpanded: dateCellExpanded)

            return cell

        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SampleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SampleTableViewCell
            cell.label.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
            if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
            }
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // Expands and contracts DatePicker Cell
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            if dateCellExpanded {
                return 250
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
        return 50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if dateCellExpanded {
                dateCellExpanded = false
            } else {
                dateCellExpanded = true
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: { () -> Void in
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .none)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            })
        }
    }
}

extension TableViewController: DatePickerDelegate {
    func setDate(_ text: String) {
        date = "Date: \(text)"
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

**DatePickerCell**

```
import UIKit

protocol DatePickerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func setDate(_ text: String)
}

class DatePickerCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var dateDelegate: DatePickerDelegate?

    var isHiddenState = true

    @IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        isHidden = isHiddenState
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {}

    @IBAction func datePickerDidChange(_: Any) {
        let result = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        print("RESULT -> \(result)")
        dateDelegate?.setDate(result)
    }
}

extension DatePickerCell: DatePickerVisibilityDelegate {
    func showCell(cellExpanded: Bool) {
        isHidden = !cellExpanded
        print("InDatePicker showCell() --> isHiddenState = \(isHiddenState)")
    }
}
```

**DateLabelCell**

```
import UIKit

class DateLabelCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!

    // let sendingTableVC = TableViewController()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}

extension DateLabelCell: DateLabelDelegate {
    func setDateLabel(_ text: String) {
        dateLabel.text = text
    }
}
```

**SampleTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class SampleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried expanding the cell inside the animation block, instead of reloading it?

Comment: @TofuWarrior Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't improve the behaviour. Dropping the dateCellExpanded if statement into the animation block doesn't make any difference and removing the CellReload simply stops the datePicker from being visible.